# Facebook Access Token - Force Expiration for Test

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, oauth, access-token

Is it possible to force a Facebook access token to expire in the new 3.2 Facebook SDK?  I need to test the auth logic in my iOS app.

I know this has been asked in the past.. but all answers I have found are not relevant.. as Facebook keeps changing their API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to force expiration of an App Access Token is to revoke that App's permissions in the user account (deleting the App from your FB account settings). That token becomes invalid immediately.  Note that upon reauthorization of the app, it's likely that you'll get the same token back, just that it'll be valid this time 'round.

Answer (score 0):

Jai's answer is a great way of doing it, here is a programmatic way of clearing your session.

Try this line of code:

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Comment: I don't think this invalidates the access token though? Not sure if the OP's requirement is to clear the session or invalidate the token.

Comment: The only way to invalidate the token is to revoke access as you stated earlier. (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the user's password on Facebook also invalidates the token.  I'm seeing some edge-cases, however, where the different auth errors behave a little differently.  If anyone knows of a way to forcibly expire the token, that would be helpful.